# Can I measure the bandwidth into a USB 3.0 port?

Tags: windows, bandwidth, usb-3

**Some background:**
On a Windows 10 PC, I have three cameras connected to a USB 3.2 Gen 2 hub, which is connected to a USB 3.0 Root Hub on my PC. I am viewing the video streams using OpenCV in Python, because I need to convert the pixel data from 16-bit to 8-bit.

[image: Cameras connected via a USB 3.2 Gen 2 hub]

**The problem:**
I can stream video from any of the cameras individually, and they work fine. I can stream video from any pair of cameras fine. But I cannot stream video from all three cameras at the same time. I see an image from each camera appear, but the video clearly isn't streaming properly, and the frame rate seems to be much less than 1 fps. One of them glitches badly.

**Analysis:**
Each camera is 1280x480 16-bit pixels, running at 100 frames per second. The data rate for each camera should therefore be a little less than 1Gbps. All three together should be about 3Gbps.

I would have thought that I should be able to stream all three videos at the same time. My hypotheses is that the USB 3.0 port is saturating.

**Questions:**

1. How can I measure the actual data rate coming into a USB port?
2. Can I detect if the USB port is saturating?
3. Are there any other ways I could analyze this problem?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your hub and all devices are running at SuperSpeed? You can try using this tool to explore what speed each port device is running at https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html

Comment: @spaceman-spiff - Yes, I have confirmed that they are all running at SuperSpeed. I can confirm it in 2 ways: Firstly, UsbTreeView reports a SuperSpeed connection. Secondly, I can measure the frame rate of the video coming in. If it's running at 100fps, then it must be a SuperSpeed connection.